# Override DOM elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In a nutshell I'm trying to target an element within the DOM, then inject a class on the fly to later alter that element.

The situation is as follows, I am working with an application that has predetermined mark up (Manage Engine). It's a tool for system work flows, creating a centralized portal for ticket logging, asset management blah blah. So I use the tool to create templates for end users to log service requests. This is accessed via a web interface portal which in turn obviously has mark up.

So far I have been able to alter specific things such as background colors on table headers for example. I achieve this by creating a rule to fire within that template upon load time. So essentially I am allowing the template to load with its predetermined code and then I am applying a for loop to alter the code once it has loaded. (Hacky I know, however its working really well).

The issue I'm running into now is that certain things within the mark up are generic (no class or id associated to the element). My plan is to target that specific generic element as a variable then add my own class to it upon load. Is there a way to target an element that has a class and then target the child elements within, save that child as a variable to then add a class on the fly with javascript.  Please see example below.

```
<tr class=test1>   
  <td>
   <input>
   <input>
   <input>
  </td>
<tr/>
```

So with the example above what I am trying to achieve is add my own class with JavaScript to the `<td>` element. Obviously if i target just `<td>` it will alter all `<td>` elements within the markup. Can i get to that specific `<td>` via the `<tr>` parent with the `test1` class. I am currently unable to use any jquery requests as the base code can not be touched.

Again I know this is a little backwards and hacky but it does work with anything I can specifically target (has a class or id). I need to be able to do this with pure JavaScript. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated, apologies if this is a noob approach or question, first time posting in a forum. Let me know if further examples or information is required.

Comment: It **sounds** like you're looking for [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You can attach an event handler to an element that exists on the page by default (such as `<body>`), and then delegate the behaviour to the element that is dynamically-created.

Comment: Have you heard of the term "paragraph" - just asking :p

Comment: Are you just looking to select elements by tag name? e.g., `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')`

Comment: ^ I was tempted to format the question, but IMO, it's still completely legible :)

Comment: Given a specific element that you select by class or whatever, you can then use various DOM navigation methods/properties to get direct children or lower-level descendants based on their relationship in the DOM tree or with methods like `.querySelectorAll()` and `.querySelector()` that let you specify element types as well as classes or IDs.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a platform for code discussion where methods are open to opinion and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelector("body").children  can get all child elements of body

Answer (score 1):

step1: Select the class. The variable **t1** will contain an Array of **tr** elements.

```
var t1 = document.querySelector('.test1');
```

step2: Get the first value from the array **t1**. So, **tr_el1** contains one **tr** element.

```
var tr_el1 = t1[0];
```

step3: Get the children of **tr**. **td_el** contains an Array of **td** elements.

```
var td_el = tr_el1.children;
```

Now you can use the **td** from the **td_el** array

Answer (score 0):

```
var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('test1')[0]
var td = tr.children[0]
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(td.children)
```

Now you got your inputs inside an array. You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the assistance, really appreciate it. The examples above helped me build a hybrid that although not exact has given me the outcome i needed.

```
var parent = document.querySelector(".roweven").children;
var nS;
for (nS = 0; nS < parent.length; nS++) {

parent[nS].style.position = "absolute";
parent[nS].style.width = "100%";
}
```

I am yet to wrap this up in a function but working as intended. Thanks again :) :)